# Unable to view Dataframes in Databricks

Tags: powerbi, databricks

I have created the following dataframes in databricks:

```
salebycountry = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/SalesByCountry.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
stock = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/Data_Stock.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
model = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/Data_Model.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
salesdetails = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/Data_SalesDetails.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
make = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/Data_Make.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
sales = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/Sales.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
```

However, when I try to view / load the data into Power BI with Power BI Desktop I am only able to see the dataframe if I issue the command .write.saveAsTable(). For example, if I want to see the dataframe called 'model', I need to write the following code model.write.saveAsTable('Model').

I've never had to do that in the past to view dataframes. I'm wondering if its because in this case I uploaded the data(csv) into databricks as opposed to ingesting the data via SQL server? But I'm not sure.

Comment: Power BI doesn't connect directly to a dataframe, it needs to be a table object to read the data out.

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/bi/power-bi.html doesn't explicitly say that it cannot connect to a dataframe, but the objects in the image show tables

Comment: @Jonee, but I've never had to write anything like model.write.saveAsTable('Model') before to access data in the past.

Comment: Have you accessed data frames before with Power BI?

Comment: Many many times - both while training and in my last job. I've never had to write.saveAsTable() before. The only difference is that I have uploaded the data from my harddrive as opposed to ingesting the data from SQL or Datalake. Which makes me believe that is why I need write.saveAsTable(), but not sure

Comment: I've just tested it, Can't see any of the dataframes in my data bricks, only tables, this has data pulled from csv, cosmosdb, sql, datalake in it. I can only see them when they have been materialized as a table

Comment: @Jonee, I was asking why I can't see the dataframes / tables in my Power BI. Can you try uploading csv into your databricks and create a dataframe from the csv. Once you've done that can you see if you can view the dataframe/table in Power BI? without write.saveAsTable() ?